# Google Play Services "Not Authentic" on Glass

Tags: java, android, google-glass

I'm attempting to get a user's current location on Glass.

Calling `mLocationClient.connect()` fails without any resolution. Then I checked if Google Play Services was available on the device with:

```
GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
```

This returns `ConnectionResult.SERVICE_INVALID`, which according to the documentation means that "The version of the Google Play services installed on this device is not authentic."

The [Setup Google Play Services SDK guide](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) does not describe that scenario.

Does this appear to be a bug on Glass itself? If so, I'll file a bug report.

Comment: Given that the GDK for on device apps hasn't been released yet, I'm not sure if a bug report will be meaningful.

Comment: FWIW, Google does address bugs that occur while sideloading apps, since this is their recommended method to build apps right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Play Services is not available on Glass at this time. You may have unpredictable results if you attempt to use it, or related features.

If this is something you care about, please let Google know. File an issue in the [Glass platform issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list) and, if possible, describe a use case you're working on that requires it. This helps the Glass team prioritize features.

Comment: Thanks, Jenny. For those interested in following, I've submitted a bug report here: http://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176

Comment: play services is much needed!  please make available on Glass.