# Google Glass and Upstream Google Cloud Messaging

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, google-glass

Google says that the [GoogleCloudMessaging object](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging) is required for [upstream messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ccs#upstream), which I believe is part of Google Play services. Glass does not have Google Play Services and has been opened as [an issue to Google](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=176).

I've gotten downstream messaging to work on Glass using an older GCM API with the help of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519469/google-cloud-messaging-on-google-glass), however none of the questions I've seen ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18519469/google-cloud-messaging-on-google-glass), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405979/why-is-glass-missing-google-play-services), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18258408/google-play-services-not-authentic-on-glass)) address upstream messaging. I was able to use the older GCM API as it did not require Google Play Services but unfortunately it doesn't support upstream messaging.

Can anyone please help me somehow implement upstream messaging on Glass? Perhaps there is a way to add Google Play Services to Glass?

Thanks

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but I just thought you should know that C2DM will be [completely shut down](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/) on July 30, 2015. There is also no way to add Play services to Glass. You could make POST requests from Glass as a form of "upstream" communication, though.

Comment: @Koh thanks for the input, I'd rather have downstream and upstream messaging go through GCM (see the flow diagrams [here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/upstream_messages_with_google_cloud_messaging/)), instead of POST requests for upstream. Also, are you sure there is no way to add Google Play Services to Glass?

Comment: No official way, sorry.

Comment: @Koh is there an unofficial way? I'm open to trying anything to hack this together